# Print new line with rake/buildr

Tags: rake, buildr

I am using buildr and I am trying to print all of my command line arguments to standard out. I have been unable to find much documentation on the print function for buildr or for rake (which buildr was built from). I already have the following:

print('Server at ip address' + SERVER)

where SERVER is the variable I store the command line argument from. The problem is that I want it on its own line and adding a '\n' after SERVER doesn't seem to do anything. Anyone know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Use puts instead of print as follows.

puts "Server at ip address #{SERVER}"

Comment: Glad you figured it out. For future reference, the reason why adding `'\n'` after SERVER didn't work is that ruby only evaluates escapes in double-quoted strings. So this would work, too:
`print 'Server at ip address ' + SERVER + "\n"`. `puts` is the more idiomatic way to do this, though.